# Sudo LDAP ldap_sasl_bind_s(): No such object

Tags: ldap, sudo

I am trying to configure CentOS 6.5 to use LDAP for sudoers and not files.

I have setup pam_ldap.conf, sudo-ldap.conf and nsswitch.

When running sudo -ll for the user I get ldap_sasl_bind_s(): No such object error.

Any help?

```
[root@time1 cacerts]# sudo -ll
LDAP Config Summary
===================
uri              ldaps://10.0.32.75
ldap_version     3
sudoers_base     ou=Sudoers,dc=ops,dc=rm
binddn           cn=Direcotry Manager
bindpw           *********
ssl              (no)
===================
sudo: ldap_set_option: debug -> 0
sudo: ldap_initialize(ld, ldaps://10.0.32.75)
sudo: ldap_set_option: ldap_version -> 3
sudo: ldap_sasl_bind_s(): No such object
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

my `binddn           cn=Direcotry Manager`
was misspelled!